# What is the difference between the following code and why this type casting is used

Tags: string, pointers, compiler-construction, casting, void-pointers

I am writing the following size of macro, I wanted to know the difference.

```
#define my_sizeof(type) (char*)(&type+1)-(char*)(&type)

#define my_sizeof(type) (void*)(&type+1)-(void*)(&type)
```

1st question is why the type casting is required, I know that if I don't type cast it, it always return 1, I checked it by running it. I want to know the significance(I mean what it tells the compiler to do).

2ndly,

What difference does it make with char* and void*.?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: the formal macro parameter `type` is wrongly named. Should be a `Var` because the macro won't work if you use `my_sizeof(int)`

Comment: Did you read a good book on C programming? Pointer arithmetic operates on typed elements!

Comment: You can't substract two `void*` pointers in standard C. But `gcc` accepts that as an extension!

Comment: Can you please point to me a good link which tells about pointer arithmetic operators.....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the second question: You cannot do that at all, since there is no pointer arithmetic for void pointers (or for pointers to incomplete types in general, for that matter).

For the first part: By definition, `sizeof(char) == 1`, so by casting the pointers to char pointers, you obtain the difference in units of 1 rather than in units of `sizeof(type)` -- in other words, you obtain precisely the value of `sizeof(type)`.